# Replacing jar when upgrade the hibernate from 3.6.5 to 4.3.5

Tags: java, hibernate, replace, jar, upgrade

Right now, My project framework is `Hibernate 3.6.5` now want to upgrade it to the latest one `Hibernate 4.3.5`.

There are some dependencies in between the .jar files.

My question is :
What all are the .jar files need to be change/replace at the time of upgrade ?

Recently I have the following .jar files for the `Hibernate 3.6.5`.

[image]

Here is the recent required .jars for the `Hibernate 4.3.5`.

[image]

**Which .jar files are need to be replace ?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Download** the latest version of **Hibernate** from the following Site **http://hibernate.org/**.

After downloading ***unzip*** the Downloaded Zip file. Now you can see **mainly three folders** like **documentation, lib, project**.

Open **lib** folder, now you can see **following folders** ***envers, jpa, optional, osgi, required.***

Add all jar files (under **required** folder) to the **classpath** and also add one more jar file (under **jpa**).

===============================================

Assume you are downloaded Hibernate Software following location.

```
Hibernate_HOME = /home/rangareddy/Hibernate/hibernate-release-4.2.7.Final
```

Jar files:

```
%Hibernate_HOME%/lib/required/antlr-2.7.7.jar
%Hibernate_HOME%/lib/required/dom4j-1.6.1.jar
%Hibernate_HOME%/lib/required/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.2.Final.jar
%Hibernate_HOME%/lib/required/hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar
%Hibernate_HOME%/lib/required/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
%Hibernate_HOME%/lib/required/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
%Hibernate_HOME%/lib/required/jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar
%Hibernate_HOME%/lib/required/jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar
%Hibernate_HOME%/lib/jpa/hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.7.Final.jar
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any need to check the dependencies or It's all about blindly replace the all .jar files.

Comment: You can replace all jar files + add driver jar file which database you are using. for example for oracle (ojdbc6.jar)

Comment: I covered almost most commonly occurred hibernate exceptions. see in my blog http://myjourneyonjava.blogspot.in/search/label/Hibernate

Comment: Please check the updated question. Still have some confusion.

Comment: mainly replace with hibernate3.jar with hibernate-core-4.3.5.jar